# Accuracy too low with very simple CNN model using Keras in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I'm new to TensorFlow so help is appreciated. My output for the model is the same as the input, only in a different shape so I expect an accuracy of 1 but am instead getting 0.0062.

**Inputs**

Each input of my dataset is in the shape of (19, 19, 1). For each of these inputs, only a random single value is set to 1 while the rest are 0. Example but with a (4, 4, 1):

```
# [[0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [0, 1, 0, 0],
#  [0, 0, 0, 0],
#  [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

**Outputs**

Each output has a shape of (361) and is essentially the flattened version of its input so it shouldn't be a problem to reach an accuracy of 1 in theory. Example:

```
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My dataset consists of 2404 of these samples.

Here's my code. Note that I've tried a combination of different loss functions and optimizers:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(19, 19, 1)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(19 * 19, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(
    optimizer='adam',
    loss=tf.keras.losses.Huber(),
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

dataset = Dataset()
inputs = dataset.input
outputs = dataset.output

model.fit(
    inputs, # (2404, 19, 19, 1)
    outputs, # (2404, 361)
    epochs=1000,
    shuffle=True,
    verbose=1
)
```

**Result**

It quickly reaches 0.0062 and remains there.

```
Epoch 10/1000
76/76 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 0.0014 - accuracy: 0.0062
```

### Update 1 - Slightly Better

Thanks for the help. After removing uses of random in my code and disabling shuffling it started hitting an accuracy of 1.00 50% of the time I ran the code. The other 50% was peaking at an accuracy of 0.0046.
When I tried to initialize weights and biases at 0, it peaked at 0.0046 100% of the time. Updating all of my TF packages almost fixed the problem, with it now being successful 90% of the time.

Comment: The issue could be in your dataset source. have you tried explicitly using your dataset input as your dataset output (reshaping it yourself)?

If your outputs are shuffled separately, you'd be effectively trying to make your CNN predict random.

Comment: Thanks. I disabled shuffling and removed all references to random and it is now successful and has an accuracy of 1.00 about 50% of the time I click run but other times, it peaks at 0.0046. For both successful and unsuccessful runs TF's output is the same and so is the dataset. I'm quite perplexed at how the same code is producing different results.

Comment: Why are you using the huber loss? That is regression loss and here you have a classification problem.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'll keep that in mind, thanks.

Comment: It is not something to keep in mind, it could be the reason why your model training fails.

Answer (score 1):

Coming out of comments to an answer. You're convolving a 1x1 kernel, then passing that to a dense layer. The ideal parameters that you want the network to learn is for all the weights in the dense layer to be the inverse of the kernel value. What's most important here though is that you're mostly passing zeroes. Any weight value in the dense layer, applied to a zero results in another zero, so the zeroes are causing your gradient to vanish.

When you initialize your weights as zeros, this turns your input vector to all zeroes, all zeros always ends learning. Can't backpropagate. When you don't do anything to the initialization, TF uses a normal distribution to initialize, centered around 0. Half the time, that initialized kernel value is negative. After convolving, you have all zeroes and a negative number. After relu you have all zeroes. Half the time it can learn - because by chance it initialized with a positive kernel value, and half the time it can't.

Try this:

```
initializer = tf.keras.initializer.Ones()
model.add(layers.Conv2D(1, (1, 1), kernel_initializer=initializer, activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=(19, 19, 1)))
```